# socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, linux, sockets, networking

I'm a newbie to socket programming.
The following program is a client program that requests a file from the server, But I'm getting the error as shown below...
My input is GET index.html and the code is
Can anyone help me with this error..?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import httplib
import sys


http_server = sys.argv[0]

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(http_server)

while 1:
cmd = raw_input('input command (ex. GET index.html): ')
cmd = cmd.split()

if cmd[0] == 'exit': 
    break


conn.request(cmd[0],cmd[1])


rsp = conn.getresponse()


print(rsp.status, rsp.reason)
data_received = rsp.read()
print(data_received)

conn.close()





input command (ex. GET index.html): GET index.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./client1.py", line 19, in <module>
conn.request(cmd[0],cmd[1])
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 910, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 947, in _send_request
self.endheaders()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 904, in endheaders
self._send_output()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 776, in _send_output
self.send(msg)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 735, in send
  self.connect()
 File "/usr/lib/python2.6/httplib.py", line 716, in connect
  self.timeout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/socket.py", line 500, in create_connection
for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Comment: What happened when you tried debugging with `print sys.argv[0]`? Did you see a real hostname that could be opened?

Comment: indenting is somewhat important to python... (and to those who are trying to interpret it...)

Comment: I got the o/p,thanks every body for replaying my qsn...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

sys.argv[0] is not what you think it is. sys.argv[0] is the name of the program or script. The script's first argument is sys.argv[1].

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the first item in `sys.argv` is the script name. So your script is actually using your filename as the hostname. Change the 5th line to:

```
http_server = sys.argv[1]
```

[More info here.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv)