# for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags): socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

Tags: python, tensorflow

On Kaggle, I am making a classifier for the MNIST dataset. For that, I followed the instructions from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/mnist/beginners).

```
import numpy as np # linear algebra
import pandas as pd # data processing, CSV file I/O (e.g. pd.read_csv)
import tensorflow as tf

# Input data files are available in the "../input/" directory.
# For example, running this (by clicking run or pressing Shift+Enter) will list the files in the input directory

from subprocess import check_output
print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

For this code, I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
10.7s
2
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 936, in connect
    (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 704, in create_connection
    for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/socket.py", line 743, in getaddrinfo
10.7s
3
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../src/script.py", line 26, in <module>
    mnist = input_data.read_data_sets("../input/", one_hot=True)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/mnist.py", line 235, in read_data_sets
10.7s
4
    SOURCE_URL + TRAIN_IMAGES)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 208, in maybe_download
10.7s
5
    temp_file_name, _ = urlretrieve_with_retry(source_url)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 165, in wrapped_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py", line 190, in urlretrieve_with_retry
10.7s
6
    return urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, filename)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 248, in urlretrieve
    with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1361, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1320, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>
```

I don't understand what this error is referring to.
Any ideas?

There is zero similarity between my question and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18897631/socket-gaierror-errno-2-name-or-service-not-known).